# runtime exception in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I have a code as shown below for data access object. On successful insertion of data in signup table,I want to extract only CustId of the signup table of that particular row. So am using UserName column to extract that particular users CustId in readCustomer() method. The program is as shown below:

```
public class RegisterDAO {

    public static int custId;


    private DataSource dataSource;

    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.dataSource = dataSource;
    }

    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public void createCustomer(Register register) {


        String sql = "INSERT INTO signup "
                + "(CustId,FirstName,LastName,Address1,Address2,Country,State,City,ZipCode,UserName,EmailId,ContactNo,MobileNo,Status)VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,'ONHOLD')";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setInt(1, register.getId());
            ps.setString(2, register.getFirstName());
            ps.setString(3, register.getLastName());
            ps.setString(4, register.getAddress1());
            ps.setString(5, register.getAddress2());
            ps.setString(6, register.getCountry());
            ps.setString(7, register.getState());
            ps.setString(8, register.getCity());
            ps.setInt(9, register.getZipCode());
            ps.setString(10, register.getUserName());
            ps.setString(11, register.getEmailId());
            ps.setString(12, register.getContactNo());
            ps.setString(13, register.getMobileNo());

            ps.executeUpdate();
            ps.close();




        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        catch (NullPointerException e1){

        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void readCustomer(String username) {

        String sql= "select * from signup where UserName= '" + username + "'";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            conn = dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                custId =rs.getInt("CustId");
                System.out.println(custId);
                 }
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        catch (NullPointerException e1){

        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

But this code is throwing a runtime exception as:

```
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'sindhura' in 'where clause'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:384)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4232)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4164)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2615)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2776)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2838)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2082)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:2212)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.executeQuery(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:96)
at com.encryption.DAO.RegisterDAO.readCustomer(RegisterDAO.java:87)
... 23 more
```

Doesn't where clause take Strings is what is my question and if it takes how to solve this?
Any help is appreciated.

This below sentence is throwing a run time exception

```
String sql= "select * from signup where UserName= '" + username + "'";
```

Comment: Can you post query created by above code? WHat is the defintion of signup table ? Did you tried to debug your code what value username  contains?

Comment: Can you please provide the complete stack trace?

Comment: Some how your code is throwing exception at ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery(); please let us know what exact query created by code with values?

Comment: @JavaBeigner Am inserting username like "John" to the table signup and CustId is a primary key which is auto incremented on each update. So in where clause in readcustomer() method am trying to fetch the CustID through rs.getInt corresponding to the user name "John" but its throwing a run time exception unknown column name John.

Comment: You need to show the data you use on insert and select. My guess is that the username contains an apostrophe. You should use a `PreparedStatement` instead of concatenating strings. Better yet: use the `getGeneratedKeys` functionality to obtain the id after insert.

Comment: at this point am just inserting a string without special symbol like apostrophe or underscore. just a String like john to the username. But my where clause is not supporting it.

Comment: You should give Mark' s proposal a chance. It may solve your problem but also be less prone to sql injection.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel could you please explain it a little more i didnt get you at the first place.

Comment: You are already using a prepared statement for the insert, you should do the same for the select. It prevents SQL injection, and therefor is a best practice (while concatenating strings into your query is **bad**).

Comment: I agree with @JavaBeigner - [edit] your question to show us the *actual SELECT statement* you are using (i.e., the contents of the `sql` variable after you do the assignment).

Answer (score 0):

please use prepared statement and **pr.setString(...)** as already suggested to you. This is the correct readCustomer(...) method to use:

```
public void readCustomer(String username) {

        String sql= "select * from signup where UserName = ?";

        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            conn = dataSource.createConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            ps.setString(1, username);


            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            if (rs.next()) {
                custId =rs.getInt("CustId");
                System.out.println(custId);
                 }
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }

        catch (NullPointerException e1){

        }
        finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    conn.close();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                }
            }
        }

    }
```